# Count across dataframe columns based on str.contains (or similar)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to count the number of cells within each row that contain a particular character string, cells which have the particular string more than once should be counted once only.

I can count the number of cells across a row which equal a given value, but when I expand this logic to use str.contains, I have issues, as shown below

```py
d = {'col1': ["a#", "b","c#"], 'col2': ["a", "b","c#"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#can correctly count across rows using equality 
thisworks =( df =="a#" ).sum(axis=1)

#can count across  a column using str.contains
thisworks1=df['col1'].str.contains('#').sum()

#but cannot use str.contains with a dataframe so what is the alternative
thisdoesnt =( df.str.contains('#') ).sum(axis=1)
```

Output should be a series showing the number of cells in each row that contain the given character string.

Comment: Why not do the logic out before using a dataframe?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I presented a simplified example. In practice, the dataframe is the result of many preceding steps, so the count can only be performed on the dataframe itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `df.apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["a#", "b","c#"], 
                   'col2': ["a", "b","c#"]})
df
  col1 col2
0   a#    a
1    b    b
2   c#   c#

df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('#'), axis=1).sum(axis=1)

  col1 col2  sum
0   a#    a    1
1    b    b    0
2   c#   c#    2
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've marked it as the answer, even though there were two other working solutions as this approach appears the most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

`str.contains` is a series method. To apply it to whole dataframe you need either `agg` or `apply` such as:

```
df.agg(lambda x: x.str.contains('#')).sum(1)

Out[2358]:
0    1
1    0
2    2
dtype: int64
```

---

If you don't like `agg` nor `apply`, you may use `np.char.find` to work directly on underlying numpy array of `df`

```
(np.char.find(df.values.tolist(), '#') + 1).astype(bool).sum(1)

Out[2360]: array([1, 0, 2])
```

Passing it to series or a columns of `df`

```
pd.Series((np.char.find(df.values.tolist(), '#') + 1).astype(bool).sum(1), index=df.index)

Out[2361]:
0    1
1    0
2    2
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've tested it and confirmed this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['#', '0'], 'col2': ['#', '#']})
df['totals'] = df['col1'].str.contains('#', regex=False).astype(int) +\
               df['col2'].str.contains('#', regex=False).astype(int)
df
#   col1 col2  totals
# 0    #    #       2
# 1    0    #       1
```

It should generalize to as many columns as you want.

Comment: How would this generalise to n columns. I appreciate I could write a loop and apply the logic you presented, but Ive seen in other posts  that looping over dataframes isn't best practice?

Comment: Hmm. I think I just meant you could write a version for as many columns as you like. I'm suddenly puzzled as to how to truly "generalize" it as I bragged so daringly.

Comment: Ah. Now I remember: It's iterating over *rows* that's the bad thing. You've likely got orders of magnitudes more *rows* than *columns*, and *rows* can take advantage of vectorization. But, you can use `timeit` to tell for sure. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tested it and agree it works. Also agree regarding the comment about iterating over columns being less bad than iterating over rows.